# While loop fails in CUDA kernel

Tags: c++, cuda

I am using GPU to do some calculation for processing words.
Initially, I used one block (with 500 threads) to process one word. 
To process 100 words, I have to loop the kernel function 100 times in my main function.

```
for (int i=0; i<100; i++)
    kernel <<< 1, 500 >>> (length_of_word);
```

My kernel function looks like this:

```
__global__ void kernel (int *dev_length)
{
   int length = *dev_length;
   while (length > 4)
   {   //do something;
          length -=4;
   }
}
```

Now I want to process all 100 words at the same time.

Each block will still have 500 threads, and processes one word (per block).

dev_totalwordarray: store all characters of the words (one after another)

dev_length_array: store the length of each word.

dev_accu_length: stores the accumulative length of the word (total char of all previous words)

dev_salt_ is an array of of size 500, storing unsigned integers.

Hence, in my main function I have

```
   kernel2 <<< 100, 500 >>> (dev_totalwordarray, dev_length_array, dev_accu_length, dev_salt_);
```

to populate the cpu array:

```
    for (int i=0; i<wordnumber; i++)
    {
        int length=0;
        while (word_list_ptr_array[i][length]!=0)
        {
            length++;
        }

        actualwordlength2[i] = length;
    }
```

to copy from cpu -> gpu:

```
    int* dev_array_of_word_length;
    HANDLE_ERROR( cudaMalloc( (void**)&dev_array_of_word_length, 100 * sizeof(int) ) );
    HANDLE_ERROR( cudaMemcpy( dev_array_of_word_length, actualwordlength2, 100 * sizeof(int),
```

My function kernel now looks like this:

```
__global__ void kernel2 (char* dev_totalwordarray, int *dev_length_array, int* dev_accu_length, unsigned int* dev_salt_)
{

  tid = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;
  unsigned int hash[N];

  int length = dev_length_array[blockIdx.x];

   while (tid < 50000)
   {
        const char* itr = &(dev_totalwordarray[dev_accu_length[blockIdx.x]]);
        hash[tid] = dev_salt_[threadIdx.x];
        unsigned int loop = 0;

        while (length > 4)
        {   const unsigned int& i1 = *(reinterpret_cast<const unsigned int*>(itr)); itr += sizeof(unsigned int);
            const unsigned int& i2 = *(reinterpret_cast<const unsigned int*>(itr)); itr += sizeof(unsigned int);
            hash[tid] ^= (hash[tid] <<  7) ^  i1 * (hash[tid] >> 3) ^ (~((hash[tid] << 11) + (i2 ^ (hash[tid] >> 5))));
            length -=4;
        }
        tid += blockDim.x * gridDim.x;
   }
}
```

However, kernel2 doesn't seem to work at all.

It seems  `while (length > 4)`  causes this.

Does anyone know why? Thanks.

Comment: put the code of the //do something, or you only have this?

Comment: the code of do //something doesn't use the variable length..

Comment: Edit the question and put it there :)

Comment: It looks all fine. Put the //do something just in case

Comment: sorry, N has been globally defined as 100*500.

Comment: Do the following test, comment all the lines inside the while(length < 4) except length -=4; and see if it works.

Comment: i tried doing printf ("%d\n", length) just after while (tid<50000), it doesnt work at all, unless i comment away while(length<4)

Comment: So test this int length = 8; and run, to see if the problem came from dev_length_array[blockIdx.x];

Comment: it still won't work, unless i comment away while(length<4)

Comment: Strange, in need, sorry can't find the error.

Comment: yea, it's alright. thanks for trying to help :)

Comment: i program in C# so i'm not fluent in C/C++ but i think you're supposed to pass single integer values to cuda kernels as simply arguments, instead of pointers. ie, `kernel(..., int length)` instead of `kernel(..., int *length)`. whereas pointers would be used to access arrays in cuda memory

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if the `while` is the culprit, but I see few things in your code that worry me:

- Your kernel produces no output. The optimizer will most likely detect this and convert it to an empty kernel
- In almost no situation you want arrays allocated per-thread. That will consume a lot of memory. Your `hash[N]` table will be allocated per-thread and discarded at the end of the kernel. If `N` is big (and then multiplied by the total amount of threads) you may run out of GPU memory. Not to mention, that accessing the `hash` will be almost as slow as accessing global memory.
- All threads in a block will have the same `itr` value. Is it intended?
- Every thread initializes only a single field within its own copy of `hash` table.
- I see `hash[tid]` where `tid` is a global index. Be aware that even if `hash` was made global, you may hit concurrency problems. Not all blocks within a grid will run at the same time. While one block will initialize a portion of `hash`, another block might not even start!

Comment: actually, my kernel function receives more argument than what I have posted. It will receive another pointer to hashtable.
So what I actually want my kernel to do is:
    1. each thread calculates one hash value.
    2. each block will calculate for one word, ie one word will have 500 hash values.
    3. the hashtable (of size 50000) will be updated with all the values, then I will copy the updated hashtable back to cpu.
    Could you suggest how can I modify the code? Thanks.

Comment: I just realized that every thread is modifying only one cell: `hash[tid]` - is this the intended behavior? Also - all threads from the same block will read exactly the same thing from `dev_totalwordarray`. So, the output in `hash[tid]` will differ only by the content of `dev_salt_`; every thread will process whole word.

Comment: yes, you are right. Each thread will process the entire word, and threads from the same block will process the same word.

Comment: Then if this is what you intend - it should work. What hides behind "does not work at all"? Fail to launch? Wrong output? ....

Comment: there is no error when I compile, but it seems the kernel isn't being processed. I tried putting a printf line inside while (tid < 50000) , nothing is being printed (unless while(length>4) has been commented away). That's why I thought (length>4) is the main cause of the problem.

Comment: Did you check the error code returned from the kernel? Call `cudaDeviceSynchronize` after the kernel call and check the error code. Check manual (http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/4_2/rel/toolkit/docs/online/group__CUDART__DEVICE_gb76422145b5425829597ebd1003303fe.html#gb76422145b5425829597ebd1003303fe)

Comment: cudaDeviceSynchronize returns a 0. This means there is no error, is this right?

Comment: It is the first CUDA API call after the kernel right? Then it means no error.